# How can I extract cell numbers/dimensions from cell size and extent?

Tags: raster, r, interpolation, sp

I need to rasterize a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object. I have a cell size of `100m` for my analysis and the raster `extent` is extracted from the `Polygon`. But, the problem is that I cannot set a `ncol` and `nrow` in the raster, because I am not sure the exact `cell dimensions` of the raster.

In the following code, I have not set the `ncol` and `nrow` of the raster, and the raster showed `cell dimensions` as following  `1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)` when printed in the console which is not representing the actual raster `dimensions`.

```
> p <- shapefile('MadaGranary')
> p
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 100.1269, 100.5313, 5.793798, 6.446769  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 1
names       : id 
value       :  1 
> crs(p) <- NULL

> # Define RasterLayer object
> ext <- extent(p)
> r.raster <- raster(ext, res = 100)
> #rasterize
> p.r <- rasterize(p, r.raster)
> p.r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : 100.1269, 200.1269, -93.55323, 6.446769  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : NA, NA  (min, max)
attributes :
 ID id
  1  1
```

Again, if I set the `ncol`, `nrow`, as well as the `resolution` of the raster, the `cell dimensions` of the raster shows the same as the above when printed  in the console.

```
> p <- shapefile('MadaGranary')
> p
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 100.1269, 100.5313, 5.793798, 6.446769  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 1
names       : id 
value       :  1 
> crs(p) <- NULL

> # Define RasterLayer object
> ext <- extent(p)
> r.raster <- raster(ext, res = 100, nrow = 450, ncol = 721 )
> #rasterize
> p.r <- rasterize(p, r.raster)
> p.r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : 100.1269, 200.1269, -93.55323, 6.446769  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : NA, NA  (min, max)
attributes :
 ID id
  1  1
```

Is there any way that I can set the `cell dimensions` or extract it from the `extent` and the `resolution` of the raster?, because having the values of `ncol`, `nrow` is important for the next step of my project analysis (interpolation) same as importance of `resolution` and `extent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coordinate system for your data is:

```
 crs : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

which is latitude-longitude in degrees.

which means you are creating rasters and extents with resolutions of 100 **degrees** not metres. Hence only one 100x100 degree cell is needed to cover your data (and most of the planet...)

Either use a fractional degree size for your output raster or transform your polygons to a projected coordinate system in metres.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your suggestion has worked for me. I can get the values I wanted by reprojecting my polygon to projected coordinate system in meters. ```> p.r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 722, 448, 323456  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 100, 100  (x, y)
extent     : 624748.7, 669548.7, 640557.8, 712757.8  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=47 +ellps=evrst48 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
attributes :
 ID id
  1  1```